# call value from another table when the value is not null

Tags: php, sql, select

I want to get the value from table `stage_cdl` if it has value and from tale `stage_vdl` if it has value.

Before this, I used this code (below) but I only receive the array until value `5` not include the table `stage_vdl_id`.

```
 $data = DB::table('stud_stage_cdl as ssc')
        ->join('license_cdl_module as lcm', 'lcm.id', '=', 'ssc.l_cdl_m_id')
        ->join('invoice_stud as is', 'is.id', '=', 'ssc.inv_stud_id')
        ->where('ssc.stud_id', $postData['stud_id'])
        ->select(
            'lcm.class_code',
            'is.invoice_num',
            'is.total',
            'is.created_at'
        )
        ->get();
```

The output:

```
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                    [class_code] => D
                    [invoice_num] => W1007INV20051
                    [total] => 1484.00
                    [created_at] => 2020-05-15 10:18:38
            )

        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [class_code] => B2
                [invoice_num] => W1007INV20052
                [total] => 1484.00
                [created_at] => 2020-05-15 10:18:55
            )

        [2] => stdClass Object
            (
                [class_code] => DA
                [invoice_num] => W1007INV20053
                [total] => 1484.00
                [created_at] => 2020-05-15 13:44:54
            )

        [3] => stdClass Object
            (
                [class_code] => B2
                [invoice_num] => W1007INV20054
                [total] => 1484.00
                [created_at] => 2020-05-15 13:48:18
            )

        [4] => stdClass Object
            (
                [class_code] => B2
                [invoice_num] => W1007INV20055
                [total] => 1484.00
                [created_at] => 2020-05-15 14:00:54
            )

    )
```

invoice_stud table

[image: Figure 1]

stud_stage_cdl table

[image: Figure 2]

stud_stage_vdl table

[image: Figure 3]

license_cdl_module table

[image: Figure 4]

license_vdl_module table

[image: Figure 5]

Here what I've done so far, there is no error but no value output. I'm very new with sql. As you can see my code, I'm trying to get the value from the lcm and lvm.

```
$data = DB::table('invoice_stud as is')
            ->join('stud_stage_vdl as ssv', 'is.stud_id', '=', 'ssv.stud_id')
            ->join('stud_stage_cdl as ssc', 'is.stud_id', '=', 'ssc.stud_id')
            ->join('license_cdl_module as lcm', 'ssc.l_cdl_m_id', '=', 'lcm.id')
            ->join('license_vdl_module as lvm', 'ssv.l_vdl_m_id', '=', 'lvm.id')
            ->where('is.stud_id', $postData['stud_id'])
            ->select(
                'lcm.class_code',
                'lvm.class_code',
                'is.invoice_num',
                'is.stage_cdl_id',
                'is.stage_vdl_id',
                'is.total',
                'is.created_at'
            )
            ->get();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this by making them as an array.

```
   $data['LicenseCDL'] = DB::table('stud_stage_cdl as ssc')
        ->join('license_cdl_module as lcm', 'lcm.id', '=', 'ssc.l_cdl_m_id')
        ->join('invoice_stud as is', 'is.id', '=', 'ssc.inv_stud_id')
        ->where('ssc.stud_id', $stud_id)
        ->select(
            'lcm.class_code',
            'is.total',
            'is.created_at'
        )
        ->get();

    $data['LicenseVDL'] = DB::table('stud_stage_vdl as ssv')
        ->join('license_vdl_module as lvm', 'lvm.id', '=', 'ssv.l_vdl_m_id')
        ->join('invoice_stud as is', 'is.id', '=', 'ssv.inv_stud_id')
        ->where('ssv.stud_id', $stud_id)
        ->select(
            'lvm.class_code',
            'is.total',
            'is.created_at'
        )
        ->get();

error_log($data); //Will receive all of them
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `COALESCE`, and choose the first non `NULL` value from `stage_cdl` and `stage_vdl` (in that order):

```
$data = DB::table('invoice_stud as is')
        ->join('stud_stage_vdl as ssv', 'is.stud_id', '=', 'ssv.stud_id')
        ->join('stud_stage_cdl as ssc', 'is.stud_id', '=', 'ssc.stud_id')
        ->join('license_cdl_module as lcm', 'ssc.l_cdl_m_id', '=', 'lcm.id')
        ->join('license_vdl_module as lvm', 'ssv.l_vdl_m_id', '=', 'lvm.id')
        ->where('is.stud_id', $postData['stud_id'])
        ->select(
            'lcm.class_code',
            'lvm.class_code',
            'is.invoice_num',
            DB::raw('COALESCE(is.stage_cdl_id, is.stage_vdl_id) AS stage_id'),
            'is.total',
            'is.created_at'
        )
        ->get();
```

Comment: Now it displays value but all the value class_code is same as in license_cdl_module

Comment: My answer is the best I can give based on the limited data and description you provided.  If you need more help, I suggest adding more data to the question.